# What is mean by Code generation libraries?

Tags: android, androidx

Today I was going through the Android libraries update by referring some videos and documents.
There was a term mentioned Code Generation Libraries.

Can any one explain what does it mean or what type of libraries are addressed as Code Generation Libraries?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: this isn't an android specific question really, i'm sure it's a common thing for most frameworks, what comes to mind when you think of code generation ? it's something which, as the name suggests, generates code, right ? dependency injection frameworks and various others do this

Comment: Most often, these are plugins or annotation processors, not common code libraries.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I came across this term while searching for Android libraries and so mentioned as Android. Thanks for rectifying my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A code generation library is a library that, if you use it, will generate some code for you, let me explain it :

One of common things in programmation is for example login forms. You use it really often and they are almost always the same structure (let say an email and a password).

If you are a web developper you might be bored to type every days the (not accurate) 10 to 30 lines of code that will create a form with :

- 2 input fields (1 for email, 1 for password), having an email "type" check etc...

So you might want to have it done real quick !
Here comes the library : by using it, you might juste use a specific syntax (not accurate) like `mylibrary.createlogin(email,pwd)`
and tadaaa I could create what you need.

I hope I've been clear enough, feel free to ask if not.